# Drools and jBPM with mule

Tags: jbpm

How to download Jbpm connector and drool component in anypoint studio? I am working on drool and jbpm with mule.I am working on 6.0.1 anypoint studio.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

No need to download the JBPM or Drools connectors, they are readily available.
For using them in a Mule application you'll need to do some configuration.
This Blog might be helpful : http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/using-mule-with-drools-and-jbpm/